# The word describing being in a steady & boring situation for long time

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What word describes the situation where you have to stay in a boring condition for a long time? For example when a doctor tells you you have to stay in bed for two days without leaving it at all! The words that come to my mind are "boring" and "tedious". I just thought there might be a better word choice.

Comment: Have you tried an on-line  thesaurus for 'boring' or 'tedious'?

Comment: @Mitch I did but there were a lot of synonyms and I wasn't sure which one to choose.

Comment: I think there might be more of a tendency to associate "boredom" with having *nothing specific to do*, and "tedium" with *repetitive mindless activity*. But that's only a tendency at best - both "boring" and "tedious" are equally applicable in OP's context, and there's no reason to look for some other, less common, alternative.

Comment: I think the word is "school". Though some say the word is "marriage".

Comment: Can you give some context then so we can help you narrow things down? If there's no restriction, then trivially any synonym will work (which is probably not what is wanted). 'Boring' and 'tedious' sound just fine for your situation. 'Tedious' has the connotation of experiencing something repetitive, where 'boring' can apply to nothing at all happening, or to something that is just not interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single word, I'd suggest [comatose](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comatose) (*characterized by lethargic inertness*). With a little more licence, you could whine about your *listless indolence* and the *dreary dullness*, the *unfaltering vapidity*, the *torpid tedium*, or the *monotonous lassitude* that appear to have taken over your days ... There really is no end to words describing boredom.

Answer (score 4):

Two days in bed? I'd call it luxury.

Doing something boring for a *really* long time can be described as being "stuck in a rut". It's a metaphor for a wheel that can't leave the groove it's made in the ground.

Answer (score 3):

In the [doldrums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doldrums).  (Wikipedia)
*The Doldrums in the Phantom Tollbooth inhabited by the Lethargarians who do nothing all day, a place where "nothing ever happens and nothing ever changes".*

[doldrums](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/doldrums) (Merriam-Webster)
a state of temporary inactivity: *the theater scene is usually in the doldrums during the summer*

Comment: +1 But, I don't think that the literary reference is really all that popular. IMO, explaining the maritime usage will be far more useful instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may use monotonous.

> **monotonous**:tediously repetitious or lacking in variety

Comment: *monotonous* **can** be boring, but not by definition.

Answer (score 1):

The word for the situation, as opposed to the state is **dreary**; continuous, boring and unpleasant.

Answer (score -1):

A "stronger" word is to *vegetate* (to be a "vegetable").

Comment: -1 I don't think *vegetating* correlates at all strongly with *boring*. People described as "vegetating" aren't normally particularly aware of being "bored". And people who say they're going to [veg out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/veg%20out) normally consider this a self-indulgent luxury (per @slim's point).

Comment: -1 Too strong; too far.

Answer (score -1):

*Boring*, *tedious*, *raylay*, *retarded*, *slow* or *not fun*.